# how can I set the the weights of networks in CNNs TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I used the following code for Convolution Neural Networks in the following link: https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/convolutional_network.py and I would like to set the parameters for my model:

my input is arrays of 35*128

an I set the following networks parameters:

```
# Network Parameters
n_input = 35*128 
n_classes = 6 
dropout = 0.75
```

could you please let me know that how can I set the weights and biases? default      values are:

```
# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    # 5x5 conv, 1 input, 32 outputs
    'wc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 1, 32])),
    # 5x5 conv, 32 inputs, 64 outputs
    'wc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 32, 64])),
    # fully connected, 7*7*64 inputs, 1024 outputs
    'wd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([7*7*64, 1024])),
    # 1024 inputs, 10 outputs (class prediction)
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, n_classes]))
}

biases = {
    'bc1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
    'bc2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
    'bd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}
```

Comment: You have already initialized them with values from a normal random distribution. `tf.random_normal()` takes care of that initialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found my solution by reading the following tutorial in tensorflow that is really helpful:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers

my input image size is 35 * 128 and I should set my parameters in dense layer ('wd1') to 9*32*64.

```
'wd1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([9*32*64, 1024]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment. So just specify clearly what exactly you mean by **set the weights and biases**. If you want the value of be set with some criteria, see this link https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_normal

Here, you can specify the mean, standard deviation and dtype of the weights and biases value .

Comment: i am familiar with random normal function but my problem is that how can i set the size of weights and biases based on my input data

Comment: Does it mean you want the shape as a variable? You don't want to hard code the shape, right?